# Remove empty spaces between icons in Eclipse toolbar

Tags: eclipse

[image]

Is it possible to change icons position or just put them together and remove empty spaces which i marker as red circles?

I use STS 3.7.2.RELEASE [Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1)] @ Windows 10

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I have tried remove %HOME%/.eclipse, workspace/.metadata and reinstalling eclipse. None of this worked. Maybe its a bug in the code and not configuration.

Comment: Got it resolved somehow. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance
Click "Restore Defaults." (in my case there was no theme selected.)
Click Apply and then OK.
Restart Eclipse.

This fixed the issue for me. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. To add to Kiran's answer, just clicking on restore defaults did not work for me. But if you change the theme to something other than what you are currently using, it might resolve the problem.

Also before you do that, take a look at 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421387
especially the 'steps to reproduce'. It looks like if you had a version of eclipse running the 'Windows' theme, and you upgraded eclipse and it changed the theme to 'default', then this issue is coming up.

Hopefully, changing the theme will work for you. I changed to classic and it did.